# sql server modify error

Tags: sql, sql-server

i m not able to modify table in SQL server. i m new to databases.

```
use work 
go 
alter table employee 
modify id varchar(20)
```

error message is-

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 
Incorrect syntax near 'modify'
```

[here is an screenshot](http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/7886/sqlr.jpg)

thanks

Comment: I'm not allowed to access that site from work - could you post the error message please?

Comment: query i wrote is:
use work
go
alter table employee modify id varchar(20)



error message is-
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'modify'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the syntax for altering a table wrong. You need:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ALTER COLUMN ExistingColumn VARCHAR(20)
```

Comment: alter table table_name alter column column_name data_type<br>
this worked...thanks raj n AdaTheDev<br>
id is not identity raj. just a name


alter table table_name modify column_name data_type<br>
this worked fine on my college comp.. but gave error on my pc

Answer (score 1):

The syntax should be

`ALTER TABLE Employee ALTER COLUMN ID VarChar (20)`

Here is the ALTER COLUMN syntax.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

Now, having said all that, I have a question for you.. Why is your ID column a VarChar as opposed to an Identity Column?

Comment: thanks raj more... still same problem

[link](http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/1329/sqq.jpg)

Comment: @Joe I assumed just as much, but asked anyway thinking it may be a design time issue that we can correct before it gets out of hand for @Jaspal

Comment: @Jaspal: Replace `MODIFY COLUMN` with `ALTER COLUMN`

Comment: alter table table_name alter column column_name data_type   this worked...thanks raj n AdaTheDev   id is not identity raj. just a name "alter table table_name modify column_name data_type"--this worked fine on my college comp.. but gave error on my pc.. any idea why?

Comment: i m just practicing thats why id is varchar:)

Comment: the `alter table .. modify column ..` is an ORACLE syntax. sql server uses `alter table .. alter column ..`